# Small project users privileges

Tags: php

I have small web application that need a users permissions system to access some content or add/edit it.

I'm using roles given to a user to manage priviliges, and also a user custom `meta` to set a custom priviliges to a specific user.

I want to know if this method is good ? if not why ? Is there is any suggestion better than put priviligies in a array ? because is too long :( .

```
    if(!function_exists('user_cap')) {
    /**
     *
     */
    function user_cap( $user_id, $cap, $action, $accesable = null ) {

        $get_user_info = get_user_info( $user_id );
        $user_role = $get_user_info->user_role;
        /**
         * Super admin role can determine custom privileges for every user 
         */
        //$user_privileges = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_privileges' );

        //

        $privileges = [
            'super_admin' => [
                'users' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'yes',
                    'update' => 'yes',
                    'delete' => 'yes'
                ],
                'projects' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'yes',
                    'update' => 'yes',
                    'delete' => 'yes'
                ],
                'locations' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'yes',
                    'update' => 'yes',
                    'delete' => 'yes'
                ],
                'reminders' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'yes',
                    'update' => 'yes',
                    'delete' => 'yes'
                ],              
                'administrations' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'yes',
                    'update' => 'yes',
                    'delete' => 'yes'
                ],              
                'locations' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'yes',
                    'update' => 'yes',
                    'delete' => 'yes'
                ],

            ],          

            'user' => [
                'users' => [
                    'create' => 'no',
                    'read' => 'no',
                    'update' => 'no',
                    'delete' => 'no'
                ],
                'projects' => [
                    'create' => 'no',
                    'read' => 'get_user_responsible_projects',
                    'update' => 'no',
                    'delete' => 'no'
                ],
                'locations' => [
                    'create' => 'no',
                    'read' => 'no',
                    'update' => 'no',
                    'delete' => 'no'
                ],
                'reminders' => [
                    'create' => 'yes',
                    'read' => 'get_user_reminders',
                    'update' => 'get_user_reminders',
                    'delete' => 'get_user_reminders'
                ],              
                'administrations' => [
                    'create' => 'no',
                    'read' => 'no',
                    'update' => 'no',
                    'delete' => 'no'
                ],              
                'locations' => [
                    'create' => 'no',
                    'read' => 'no',
                    'update' => 'no',
                    'delete' => 'no'
                ],

            ],
        ];

        $role_privilege = $privileges[$user_role][$cap][$action];

        if($privilegs == 'yes') {

            return true;

        }elseif($privilege == 'no') {

            return false;

        }else{

            $privilege = call_user_func($privilege);
            if(in_array($accesable, $privilege) {

                return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }
}

if(!function_exists('user_can')) {
    /**
     * @param   int     $user_id
     * @param   string  $cap
     * @param   string  $action
     */
    function user_can( $user_id, $cap, $action ) {

        return user_cap( $user_id, $cap, $action );

    }
}

if(!function_exists('current_user_can')) {
    /**
     * @param   string  $cap
     * @parzm   string  $action
     *
     * @return mixed (string on success|boolean on failure)
     */
    function current_user_can( $cap, $action ) {

        $current_user = current_user();

        if(empty($current_user)) {
            return false;
        }

        return user_can($current_user->id, $cap, $action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be many, many ways to structure these permissions.  I'll offer a pathway that doesn't totally abandon your original script.

1. Don't bother writing out all of the `super_admin` permissions until the day when you actually have a `no` setting for them.  Just write a simple condition on that single variable and an early return.
2. Only store the `yes` and callback values.  This will save lots of eye strain and scrolling.  Have your program assume `No` permission by default and only declare the access granting keys.  By doing this, you can write an early `false` return if the set of keys are not listed.
3. If the listed value in the permissions lookup array is `yes`, early return `true`.
4. Leave the "heaviest" action 'til last.  This return is the final determining line, so it can be an inline condition on `return`.

The adjusted script might look like this:  (notice no typos and no temporary variables)

```
function user_cap($user_id, $cap, $action, $accesable = null) {
    $get_user_info = get_user_info($user_id);
    $user_role = $get_user_info->user_role;

    $privileges = [
        'user' => [
            'projects' => [
                'read' => 'get_user_responsible_projects',
            ],
            'reminders' => [
                'create' => 'yes',
                'read' => 'get_user_reminders',
                'update' => 'get_user_reminders',
                'delete' => 'get_user_reminders'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    if ($user_role == 'super_admin') {
        return true;
    }

    if (!isset($privileges[$user_role][$cap][$action])) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($privileges[$user_role][$cap][$action] == 'yes') {
        return true;
    }

    return in_array($accesable, call_user_func($privileges[$user_role][$cap][$action]));
}
```